# SQLAlchemy: Run aggregate functions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have table with two columns:

- Name
- Days

Intersystems Cache Database

```
|name  |days   |
|'Tom' |'2,3,5'|
|'Bill'|'0,3'  |
|'Ted' |'1,6'  |
```

0 - Monday
1 - Tuesday
...
6 - Sunday

I want to take back every name whose time it is today.

There are %LISTFROMSTRING(string, delimiter) function
so:

```
db.query(Table.name).filter(
    literal(
        str(datetime.utcnow().weekday())
    ).in_(func.LISTFROMSTRING(Table.days, ",")
)
```

`datetime.utcnow().weekday()` - returns integer (0-6) accordingly

But SQLAlchemy cannot recognize this function because of the $ symbol at the beginning.

How can I use the %LISTFROMSTRING aggregate function with SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQLAlchemy column operator **[contains](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.contains)**

```
db.session.query(
   Table.name
).filter(
   Table.days.contains(str(datetime.utcnow().weekday()))      
).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query you need

```sql
db.session.query(
    TempTable,
).filter(
    TempTable.days.contains(
        cast(func.extract('isodow', func.now()) - 1, String)
    )
)
```

OR

```sql
db.session.query(
    Table.name
).filter(
    func.extract('isodow', func.now()) - 1 == any_(  -- check if today is subset of any days
        func.cast(  -- split days by comma and cast to array of integer
            func.string_to_array(Table.days, ','), 
            ARRAY(Integer)
        )
    )
).all()
```